# Converting a line to a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, transformation

I am working with a line which has the following information.

```
[
 {x: 384, y: 360, percentage: '0%'},
 {x: 460.79998779296875, y: 360, percentage: '10%'},
 {x: 537.5999755859375, y: 360, percentage: '20%'},
 {x: 614.4000244140625, y: 360, percentage: '30%'},
 {x: 691.2000122070312, y: 360, percentage: '40%'},
 {x: 768, y: 360, percentage: '50%'},
 {x: 844.7999877929688, y: 360, percentage: '60%'},
 {x: 921.5999755859375, y: 360, percentage: '70%'},
 {x: 998.4000244140625, y: 360, percentage: '80%'},
 {x: 1075.199951171875, y: 360, percentage: '90%'},
 {x: 1152, y: 360, percentage: '100%'} 
]
```

The line starts at (384,360) and ends at (1152,360). Between 0% to 100% I calculated 9 intervals with 10% gap to calculate x and y coordinates at the respective percentage, by line parameterization, such as

```
@ 10% -> (1152-384)*0.1+384 = 76.8+384 = 460.80
@ 20% -> (1152-384)*0.2+384 = 76.8+384 = 537.60
```

Graphically, it looks like this

[image: pic]

With this information, if I convert this line to a circle, how do I find the coordinate of each of these (x,y) interval coordinates on the circle?

The center coordinate of the circle is `x coordinate @0%, y coordinate @0%+radius=> (384,360+circumference/2π)=>(384,482.231)`.

[image]

I am not a mathematician, apologies I don't know how to provide mathematical notations here.

Comment: What is a “line coordinate” and a “circle coordinate “? Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is, if I convert the line to a circle, what would be the new coordinate of each of these line coordinates? For example,  if I want to find this line coordinate`{x: 460.79998779296875, y: 360, percentage: '10%'}` on the circle, what would be the new coordinate?

Comment: What are the coordinates of center of the circle?

Comment: Also, I don’t understand the meaning of “percentage” after the coordinates.

Comment: The center coordinate of the circle is `x coordinate @0%, y coordinate @0%+radius=> (384,360+circumference/2π)=>(384,482.231)`.

Comment: Think of percentage as, if I have a straight line and I want to know the x,y coordinate of that line at a certain percentage of the length of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a line segment between the points:
$$
P_1=(384,360)\\
P_2=(1152,360)
$$
hence having length $1152-384=768$. You want this to be transformed to become circumference of a circle, hence having radius:
$$
r=\frac{768}{2\pi}
$$
Finally, you want a given point between $P_1$ and $P_2$ to be mapped to the corresponding point on the circle. You have already parametrized the line with a function having:
$$
f(0)=P_1\\
f(1)=P_2
$$
namely:
$$
f(t)=P_1+t\cdot(P_2-P_1)=(384+t\cdot768,360)
$$
The circle has center:
$$
C=P_1+(0,r)=\left(384,360+\tfrac{768}{2\pi}\right)\approx(384,482.23)
$$
The correspondingly parametrized version of the circle will then be (written as a vector for better readability):
$$
\begin{align}
g(t)
&=
C+r\cdot\langle\sin(t\cdot 2\pi),-\cos(t\cdot 2\pi)\rangle\\
\quad\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
384+\tfrac{768}{2\pi}\cdot\sin(t\cdot 2\pi)\\
\quad\\
360+\tfrac{768}{2\pi}\cdot\left(1-\cos(t\cdot 2\pi)\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Your coordinate system has $y$-axis upside down, I think, but here is a dynamic GeoGebra-applet showing how it works:

[Link to GeoGebra-applet](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/zt5nfdzz)

Comment: Thanks for this. I will check this with my production code and report back.

Comment: Would not this `f(t)=P1+t⋅(P2−P1)=(384+t⋅768,360)` be `f(t)=P1+t⋅(P2−P1)=(384+t⋅768,0)`

Comment: @smpa01: Well, $P_2-P_1=(768,0)$ so since this $y$-coordinate is zero, adding $t$ times this will not alter the $y$-coordinate.

Comment: BTW, the standard parametrization of a line between two points is $(1-t)\cdot P_1+t\cdot P_2$ which actually equals $P_1+t\cdot(P_2-P_1)$. This works for ANY pair of points in the 2D-plane. The method even extends to more dimensions.